# Why custom fields in profile of filament-breezy are not filled with data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

In Laravel 10/Filamentphp 3 multi tenancy app I added jeffgreco13/filament-breezy v2.2.1.1 package and added custom fields
in app/Livewire/CustomProfileComponent.php, which I created with artisan command. Problem is that opening "/app/branch-name/my-profile"
url my custom fields are not filled with data of current logged user with code like :

```
class CustomProfileComponent extends MyProfileComponent
{
    protected string $view = "livewire.custom-profile-component";

    public array $data;

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        \Log::info(varDump($user, ' -1 $user::'));
        $employee = Employee::getByUserId($user->getAttribute('id'))->first();


        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required(),

                Select::make('branch_id')->label('Branch')
                    ->prefixIcon(BranchHelper::getIcon())
                        ->preload()
                    ->options(Branch::query()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    //->default($user->getAttribute('branch_id'))
                    ->required(),
            ])
            ->statePath('data');
```

Both 'name' and 'branch_id' fields are empty, even if I uncommented line with default method and valid data...
Not sure what must be provided in statePath method ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**

This CustomProfileComponent component has no $this->form var, but has $form var, which is passed as param to form method
As my profile form consists of 2 tables : users  employees I tried to use fill method :

```
<?php


class CustomProfileComponent extends MyProfileComponent
{
    protected string $view = "livewire.custom-profile-component";

    public array $data;

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $this->data = $user->attributesToArray();
        $employee = Employee::getByUserId($user->getAttribute('id'))->first();

        \Log::info(varDump($employee, ' -1 $employee::'));
//        $userAttributes = $user->attributesToArray();
        if($employee) {
            $this->data = Arr::collapse([$this->data, $employee->attributesToArray()]);
            \Log::info(varDump($this->data, ' -1 $this->data::'));
            // I check and see that array above has 'branch_id' key
        }
        $form->fill($this->data);
        ...
```

Any way Select component has no item selected...

```
    What is wrong in my code ?
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I do not have any error, but select option is not selected, as I expected

Comment: you mean when you open the page to update your profile the select is not selecting the previous option from database correct?

Comment: Yes, current value in db is not selected

Comment: ok to do that i used the fill form as you did, maybe you forgot to fill the select value or filled another value by mistake, try to debug the data before fill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use $this->form->fill($data);

like this example:

```
$this->data['branch_id'] = auth()->user()->branch_id;
$this->data['name'] = auth()->user()->name;
$this->data['email'] = auth()->user()->email;
$form->fill($this->data);
```

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK

Comment: Looks like to make it working I just beed to fill $this->data, but not calling form->fill (I checked parent classes) and did not find any fill method. Please remove line form->fill above and I will accept it.

Comment: yeah in your case there is no $this->form, i wrote the code that i used but i was using mount function in a custom page not in profile component. so i updated the answer